# ITCSS: where to put CSS animations?

Tags: css, itcss

I'm using ITCSS for my latest project.

The layers of the triangle are the follows:

- Settings — used with preprocessors and contain font, colors
  definitions, etc. In this layer is common define the variables that
  can customize the template.
- Tools — globally used mixins and functions. This layer is only used
  if we use a preprocessor as SASS.
- Generic — reset and/or normalize styles, box-sizing definition, etc.
  It is important to note that this is the first layer of the triangle
  that generates CSS.
- Elements — styling for bare HTML elements (like H1, A, header,
  footer, …). These come with default styling from the browser so we
  must to redefine them here.
- Objects — class-based selectors which define undecorated design
  patterns, for example media object known from OOCSS such as list,
  radio-button.
- Components — specific UI components. The components of our page, for
  example button, card, concrete-list, etc..
- Utilities — utilities and helper classes with ability to override
  anything which goes before in the triangle.

Taken from https://dev.to/carlillo/understanding-itcss-real-case-using-itcss-in-a-ghostcms-blog-1p9b

but where do I put my css animations?

```
 @keyframes fadeIn {
     from {
         opacity: 0;
     }

     to {
          opacity: 1;
     }
 }
```

1 and 2 must not generate CSS therefore I expect number 3 (Generic) is the right section?

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: According to the article you did link yourself, they go into the utilities file. 'The utility layer is reserved as a “catch-all” in our case we have left here animations that could have gone perfectly to lower layers since they are generic but we have preferred to transfer it to utilities'

Comment: @ThomasScheffer yes, but I disagree wholeheartedly that animations are utilities or overrides - hence the question :)

Comment: I agree. After I made the comment I did a quick search myself and found a resolution, using more of less the method from Persijn's answer(without the utilisation of the tools layer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Animations in itcss

If the animation is used multiple places define it in the **Object layer**.
If you are using a preprossor and create animations for different components put it in the **Tools layer**.
If its a one time only animation it should be placed in the **Component layer**

Comment: I much prefer this. You could have a mixin/placeholder in tools but that would generate CSS so, therefore, I could discount that. Object for all and Component for one-offs IMO.